# Existence of a file given its path

Tags: c, linux, filesystems

Given the path, is there a way to find out whether the file exists without opening the file?

Thanks

Comment: It's worth mentioning that if you intend to do something if the file exists, you should just attempt to do that thing. It's possible what you're is an anti-pattern called Look Before You Leap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most efficient way is [`access`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/access.html#tag_16_10) with the `F_OK` flag.

`stat` also works but it's much heavier weight since it has to read the inode contents, not just the directory.

Comment: Corrected link: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/access.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **[stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat)** system call. Make sure though that you check `errno` for the correct error because `stat` may return `-1` for a number of other reasons/Failures.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
main()
{
        struct stat BUF;
        if(stat("/Filepath/FileName",&BUF)==0)
        {
                printf("File exists\n");
        }
}
```

---

Another way is by using the **[access](http://linux.die.net/man/2/access)** function.

```
#include <unistd.h>

main()
{
        if(access("/Filepath/FileName", F_OK) != -1 ) 
        {
               printf("File exists\n");
        } 
        else 
        {
               printf("File does not exist\n");
        }       
}
```

Comment: If you want to know whether the file exists and is accessible (proper permissions, have read and/or write access, etc.) some recommend just opening it and seeing whether the open succeeded.  `stat` makes sense when you need additional information about the file, or when you'd like to know if it exists even if you can't open it... though it's still possible to not even have enough access to stat an existing file, so even then you may need to check `errno` on failure.

Comment: @Dmitri: The OP is looking for alternatives to check existence of the file and specifically states without trying to opening it. We do not know what scenario OP has to impose such restrictions/conditions. Given that `stat` is a viable option and the answer states that.

Comment: I didn't intend to dispute the answer (I upvoted it, actually).  I was just elaborating a bit, precisely _because_ we don't know the reasons the other poster wants to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>

int rc;
struct stat mystat;
rc = stat(path, &mystat);
```

Now check rc and (maybe) errno.

EDIT 2011-09-18 addendum:

Both access() and stat() return 0 if the path points to a non-file (directory, fifo,symlink, whatever)

In the stat() case, this can be tested with "((st_mode & S_IFREG) == S_IFREG)".
Best way still is to just try to open the file with open() or fopen().

Answer (score -1):

Try to remove it (unlink()). If successful, it doesn't exist anymore. If unsuccessful,
interpret errno to see if it exists :)

Comment: ...and then restore it from backups lOl